# Ajax passing data to php with POST method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I was trying to display the value on the page but the display of the value happens on the console.log.

**script.js**

```
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('.variant_model').on('click', function()
            {
                var model_id = $(this).attr("id");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    data: 'model_id='+model_id,
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

**script.php**

```
if(isset($_POST["model_id"]))
{
    $return = $_POST["model_id"];
    var_dump($return);
    die();
}
    $result = $DB->query('SELECT variant_model_name FROM variant_model WHERE model_id = "'.$return.'"');
...
```

Comment: That is because you are logging the output in console `console.log(data);` . Where do you want to display the output? Get the elements id or class and use `append()` or `html()`

Comment: @bipen I would like to pass the value in a variable in my php script with the POST method.

Comment: Passing the value to your PHP script is what the AJAX request does already. If you want to do anything else with the response it gives back on the client side than just logging it to console - then _do so_.

Comment: use  `data:{ model_id : model_id },` ... NOT ***data: 'model_id='+model_id,***

Comment: well @Eddie that's the right way to do it but the one in the question also work. For nadir:  I think you ajax call looks fine just that you have to modify your php code. put `$result = $DB->query('SELECT variant_model_name FROM variant_model WHERE model_id = "'.$return.'"');` inside the if condition. Remove die and return result.

Comment: he has `var_dump($return);` there. It should work and that why he is getting posted value in console

Answer (score 1):

In your script.php, instead of var_dump(), you can just echo it:

```
echo $return;
exit();
```

Then in your script.js you can assign it to an element body with .html() method:

```
$('#showmodelid').html(data);
```

For this to work, you have to have an element with id 'showmodelid' in your HTML body:

```
<h1>Model ID is: <span id="showmodelid"></span></h1>
```

You can also keep the console.log() statement for debugging. But that is not for showing stuff on the page.

UPDATED

---

modify script.php as follows:

```
$return = $POST['model_id'];
$result = $DB->query('SELECT variant_model_name FROM variant_model WHERE model_id = "'.$return.'"');
echo json_encode($result);
exit();
```

Now update your script.js as follows:

```
// in ajax response
parseddata = JSON.parse(data);
$('#showmodelname').html(parseddata.variant_model_name);
```

Have an html element to show the result:

```
<h1>Model Name is: <span id="showmodelname"></span></h1>
```

That should do it.

Comment: Well this will return whatever he posted since in php he has `$return = $_POST["model_id"];`. If this is correct, then there is no need to make an ajax call.

Comment: @bipen technically and logically yes. It will make sense if the query gets executed and return its result. But this sample code, simply var dumps the $return before executing the query so as for his answer this should be do it.

Comment: I would like to pass data in PHP to use it with SQL.
How can I use your code ?

Comment: @nadirkrid your current sql statement is ok. It should give you a matching result from db. What you've got to do is replace the var_dump() with the sql query statement. output the result with json_encode($result). Then in your script.js you have to decode the result with res = JSON.parse(data); Then you'll be able to access the result like data.field_1, data.field_2 ect.

Comment: @AmilaDev I try it and I have : {"queryString":"SELECT variant_model_name FROM variant_model WHERE model_id = \"\""}
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Comment: @nadirkrid check if your $DB->query() method is made to fetch a row from its resultset? there must be some fetchRow() variant

Comment: Ok, I'll check. I have also in console.log() : SyntaxError:  JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: @nadirkrid thats becasue the php script returning an error. When JSON.parse tries to parse the incoming data, it fails. So you have to fix the error from PHP side, and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. After seeing all the post. I think I should tell you what's happening here. Try it out.

**Solution**

```
if(isset($_POST["model_id"]))
{
    $return = $_POST["model_id"];
    $result = $DB->query('SELECT variant_model_name FROM variant_model WHERE model_id = "'.$return.'"');
    return $result; 
}
```

**Reasoning**

Since you have

```
var_dump($return);
die();
```

in PHP, even though the value is posted properly the `die()` exit the function call which will return the posted value to ajax. Remove `die()` and your code should work. Also, I shifted the query inside if condition as I am assuming it should only do the query if `model_id` is present. Anyways do what you need here.

Once you apply the changes above, if you check your console `console.log(data)` should give you all query result. Now you can show it in the page by using [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)